# How to remain the style of "outline text" to generate catalog in a RTF template when use BI Publisher to change it to a DOCX?

Tags: xml, ms-word, docx, rtf, bi-publisher

The problem is when I edit a RTF template by BI publisher in MS Word and  want to use it to generate a DOCX, the "outline text" in RTF like "Title" will be "main text" style in the DOCX.So that I cannot gengerate catalog in the DOCX, cause there is no text with "outline text" style.I cannot find how to use MS Word's feature or XLS language in BI Publisher to solve that.

I have tried to use MS Word's Multi-level list and setting "outline text" style in Paragraphs, but when changed to a DOCX, the text keeps Multi-level, but in Paragrahs it turns to "main text".I also tried some XLS-FO language, like

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <fo:block font-size="18pt" font-weight="bold" fo:outline-level="1">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

and it seems does not work, the DOCX will still show these codes.
Can I use BI publisher or MS word or change the RTF template's content  so that the DOCX will keep "outline style" or there is another way to gengeate catalog in the DOCX?